# Slow detection of wireless card

Tags: wifi, intel, iwlwifi

Recently I noticed my wireless card isn't "available" until 60s after boot.

When X is ready I run

```
%> ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

Then about 20s later I can see this in dmesg, and wlan0 is ready afterwards.

```
[   61.713944] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.168.5.3 build 42301 op_mode iwldvm
[   61.713958] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   61.713959] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS disabled
[   61.713961] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING disabled
[   61.713962] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 AGN, REV=0xB0
```

I'm not sure why but this is quite unusual, anyone know where I should be looking at?

I'm running Arch Linux, with customized 3.15.10 kernel.

Comment: It's a hard to debug problem, but i would attack the following points to start the investigation: 1 - Check if there isn't any "power saving" feature that could be delaying the firmware+module load. 2 - Check for firmware bugs on Intel changelogs(I'm using version 18.168.6.1, and it seems your firmware version is a little old: 17.168.5.3). 3 - Try to see if this error reproduces using a pre-packaged kernel or using the Arch Linux LTS kernel.

Comment: @nwildner Ha, the kernel in stock works just fine, I'll try to update the firmware first, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Thanks @nwildner I've rebuilt the kernel and it worked ;-P

Comment: Great. If you have changed any kernel setting or used a different firmware version, please post your solution as a answer to this question. This could help others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about it.

Upgraded kernel to `3.17.6`, no change to kernel configuration and it just worked.

I guess the NetworkManager or udev or whatever userspace tools that changed it behavior, which is incompatible with older kernels.

If someone has better answer I will have this removed